# Que tanto cambia un archivo PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

Pregunta simple:
Se puede usar el mismo código en PHP con MySql y PostgreSql?. Por ejemplo este simple login:

```
<?php  
 require('db_connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['user_id']) and isset($_POST['user_pass'])){

// Assigning POST values to variables.
$username = $_POST['user_id'];
$password = $_POST['user_pass'];

// CHECK FOR THE RECORD FROM TABLE
$query = "SELECT * FROM `user_login` WHERE username='$username' and Password='$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1){

//echo "Login Credentials verified";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Login Credentials verified')</script>";

}else{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Invalid Login Credentials')</script>";
//echo "Invalid Login Credentials";
}
}
?>
```

Se conecta a una base de datos MySql, se puede usar el mismo código para conectarse a PostgreSql?

Comment: No te hago una respuesta porque estoy del celu y puedo tardar horas, pero fíjate de adaptar este ejemplo. Fíjate que cambian los nombres de varias funciones con respecto a las que se usan para pegarle a una db MySQL https://ricardogeek.com/conectarse-a-postgressql-usando-php/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Mediante PDO (PHP Data Object), puedes manejarlo para que tu código de hecho que de portable a otros gestores de bases de datos, además tus consultas quedarían mas seguras contra inyecciones sql.

- Tu cñodigo actual si tendría algunas variantes dado que esta orientado únicamente al driver que conecta con el motor de bases de datos MySQL

Empecemos por tu conexión que pudiera quedar así dentro de una función:

```
function conexion()
{
    $conexion = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=algo", "usuario", "contrasenia");
    return $conexion;
}
```

Posterior en tu archivo .php principal modificaremos lo siguiente:

- Haremos uso de consultas preparadas
- Haremos un `SELECT COUNT(*)` para que la consulta sea capaz de devolver un número identificando si las condiciones regresaron 1 o 0 filas
- En lugar de pasar de forma directa las variables a tu consulta, lo hacemos por medio de los *marcadores de nombre* para realizar una interpolación en el método `execute()`
- Para poder evaluar en el código si la consulta devolvió o no registros, entonces hacemos uso de la función `columnCount`

Propuesta de código:

```
<?php 

require('db_connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['user_id']) and isset($_POST['user_pass']))
{

    // Assigning POST values to variables.
    $username = $_POST['user_id'];
    $password = $_POST['user_pass'];

    // CHECK FOR THE RECORD FROM TABLE
    $consulta = conexion()->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user_login` 
                                    WHERE username=:username 
                                    and Password=:password");

    $consulta->execute(array(":username" => $username, ":password" => $password));

    if ($consulta->columnCount() == 1)
    {
        //echo "Login Credentials verified";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Login Credentials verified')</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Invalid Login Credentials')</script>";
        //echo "Invalid Login Credentials";
    }
}
```

**Importante**

> Si vas a usar PostgreSQL a través de una instancia de la clase PDO; entonces debes asegurarte que en tu **php.ini** tengas habilitadas las siguientes extensiones:

```
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pgsql
```

Es decir no deben tener un símbolo de punto y coma al inicio de su nombre

**Referencias**

- [PDO PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php)
- [columnCount](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.columncount.php)

Answer (score 0):

Las funciones son distintas para PostgreSQL, ademas, la sintaxis de los querys suelen variar un poco, te dejo un enlace a la documentacion de PostgreSQL desde la pagina oficial de PHP.

[Documentacion PostgreSQL desde la pagina oficial de PHP.](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pgsql.php)

> Suponiendo que el archivo "db_connect.php" ya esta adaptado a PostgreSQL, el resto del codigo del login quedaria de la siguiente manera:

Pregunta simple: Se puede usar el mismo código en PHP con MySql y PostgreSql?. Por ejemplo este simple login:

```
<?php  
 require('db_connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['user_id']) and isset($_POST['user_pass'])){

// Assigning POST values to variables.
$username = $_POST['user_id'];
$password = $_POST['user_pass'];

// CHECK FOR THE RECORD FROM TABLE
$query = "SELECT * FROM `user_login` WHERE username='$username' and Password='$password'";

$result = pg_query($connection, $query);
if (!$result) {
    echo "Ocurrió un error.\n";
 }

$count = pg_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1){

//echo "Login Credentials verified";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Login Credentials verified')</script>";

}else{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Invalid Login Credentials')</script>";
//echo "Invalid Login Credentials";
}
}
?>
```